# How can we perform rollback on custom transformed data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use custom transformation in one of my model like this:

```
 App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
        questionName: DS.attr('string'),
        parentQuestionId: DS.attr('number'),
        position: DS.attr('number'),
        questionLayoutId: DS.attr('number'),
        questionLayoutName: DS.attr('string'),
        attributes: DS.attr('raw'),
        childQuestions: DS.hasMany('question', {async: true})
    });
```

and my transformation is defined as :

```
 App.RawTransform = DS.Transform.extend({

        deserialize: function (serialized) {
            var obbj = Ember.Object.create();
            for (var key in serialized) {
                obbj.set(key, serialized[key]);
            }
            return  obbj;
        },
        serialize: function (deserialized) {
            return JSON.stringify(deserialized);
        }
    });
```

With this setup, the rollback doesnot work for transformed properties. Here is a jsBin link to demo the issue: http://jsbin.com/uBAZOfO/1/

so if you change the input fields and hit rollback, only name gets rollbacked. Is there any workaround to achieve rollback on the transformed data??

Thanks,
Dee

Comment: I've added a detailed Q&A about this issue right here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886068/ds-attr-isnt-affected-by-ds-rollbackattributes/40886069#40886069

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will save some time for people who are trying to achieve the same, I was able to do rollback by writing following generic transformation:

```
AS.RawTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
/**
 * Recursively read through the json object/array and convert it into Ember.Object and Ember.ArrayProxy respectively
 *
 * @param {Object} Javascript object
 * @returns {Object} Ember Object or ArrayProxy
 */
deserialize: function (serialized) {

    if (!(serialized)) {
        serialized = {};
    }

    var recursiveDeserializer = function (object, data) {
        if (!(object)) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Array]') {
                object = Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, { content: Ember.A()});
            } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Object]') {
                object = Ember.Object.create();
            }
        } else {
            //used when rolling back
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Array]') {
                var all = object.toArray();
                all.forEach(function (item) {
                    object.removeObject(item);
                });
            }
        }

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Object]') {
            for (var _key in data) {
                object.set(_key, recursiveDeserializer(null, data[_key]));
            }
        } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data) === '[object Array]') {
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                object.get('content').push(recursiveDeserializer(null, data[i]));
            }
        } else {
            return data;
        }
        return object;
    };

    var ret = recursiveDeserializer(null, serialized);

    ret.reopen({
        /**
         * This function reverts back changes made to the content of Ember Object/Array
         * */

        rollback: function () {
            var self = this;
            Ember.run(function () {
                recursiveDeserializer(self, serialized);
            });

        }
    });
    return ret;
},

/**
 * Recursively read through the Ember.Object/Ember.ArrayProxy and convert it into javascript array or object
 *
 * @param {Object} Ember ArrayProxy or Object
 * @return {Object} Javascript object
 * */
serialize: function (deserialized) {

    var recursiveSerializer = function (object, data) {
        if (!(object)) {
            if (data instanceof Ember.ArrayProxy) {
                object = [];
            } else if (data instanceof Ember.Object) {
                object = {};
            }
        }

        /**
         * Couldn't use instanceof command to check the type
         * because for some reason at this point the data
         * is seen as Object even if it is an array
         * */

        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(object) === '[object Object]') {
            for (var _key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(_key) &&
                    _key.indexOf('__ember') < 0 &&
                    _key.indexOf('_super') < 0 &&
                    Ember.typeOf(data.get(_key)) !== 'function'
                    ) {
                    object[_key] = recursiveSerializer(null, data[_key]);
                }
            }
        } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(object) === '[object Array]') {
            data.forEach(function (d) {
                object[object.length] = (recursiveSerializer(null, d));
            });
        } else {
            return data;
        }
        return object;
    };

    return recursiveSerializer(null, deserialized);
}
});
```

The only drawback here is that I cannot just do model.rollback, I have to perform rollback on each 'raw' data type. eg: model.get('tranformedData').rollback()

But I think this is at-least a start. It would be nice to also add observers here to check 
if the data is dirty or not.

Comment: Just what i needed!  I did need to change one thing about this as this code is about 5 years old.  As of Ember 1.13, ArrayProxy no longer contains the function createWithMixins.  I just used create instead and dropped the Mixin argument.

Answer (score 0):

The transformations don't get applied except on find/save.

The problem is ED doesn't know how to track your pojo living on your record, so it doesn't show up as a dirty attribute, unless you changed the entire pojo, not just an property on the pojo.

You might consider making it into some relationship, or non pojo data type

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "some relationship, or non pojo data type"? Do you mean that I should define a model for the attributes itself, that is kinda difficult because the data structure is not fixed and can have different properties.

Comment: If it's dynamic then a relationship won't help, you may need to manually backup and revert it.  You can think of your pojo as a relationship, the record is only dirty when the relationship changes, not when an attribute on the relationship changes.

Comment: you might be able to do an `Attribute` model that has a name and value, and your question model can have a `hasMany('attribute')`

Comment: yeah sadly like I mentioned before, I cannot make a model for attributes because we are not sure what's the server is gonna throw out for attributes, it doesn't follow specific structure.