# How to apply custom transformation when manually creating new record using store.createRecord

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model that uses one of the custom transform like:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    questionName: DS.attr('string'),
    attributes: DS.attr('myCustomTransform')    
});
```

Now I want to create a Question record like :

```
var newQuestion = store.createRecord('question', {"questionName":"abc", "attributes":{....}});
```

It creates a record but it doesn't apply the custom transformation to the loaded record(or attributes). Any idea how I can apply the transformations when records are manually created??

Thanks,
Dee

**UPDATE : WORKING SOLUTION **

My model looks like this:

```
AS.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    questionName: DS.attr('string'),
    answers: DS.hasMany('answer'),
    childQuestions: DS.hasMany('question', {async:true})
});
```

The add logic looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "questions",
            data: {"templateId": templateQuestionId, "parentQuestionId": someId},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        }).done(function (data) {


          /*
          data looks something like
{"questions":[
      {"id":122,
      "questionName":"some question name",
      "attributes": {"pinned":false,"randomized":false},
      "answers":[1,2],
      "childQuestions":[]
      }]
,"answers":[
      {"id":1,"answerText":"some text"}
     ,{"id":2,"answerText":"some text"}
  ]}
   */
                store.pushPayload('question', data);
                var questionId = data.question.id;
                store.find('question', questionId).then(function(question){
                    parent.get('childQuestions').pushObject(question);
                });
                self.send('toggleBody');
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformations are applied during transfer to and from server, not during get/set.

Comment: So there is no way we can apply transformation to json data that we provide to the ember(maybe the data is not from the server but manually provided)?

Comment: not during creation, ember data assumes you have complete control of the code at that point and can manipulate it how you need.  ignore my previous rant about usimg the setter, i missed what you were doing.  why would you need to deserialize the obj?

Comment: It is kinda related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549321/how-can-we-perform-rollback-on-transformed-data. I create a new question record based on a template, but template itself is not part of the question model .For eg:I would create a new question with POST request to /question?template_id=1. That request will create a new question in the db and then return the json data in proper Ember format. I wanted to make use of that data and append a record in the client side. When doing so the attributes data seems to be plain json object but not the deserialized Ember.Object

Comment: I do realize that other easy way to do things would be to just ask store for the new question model data(since I already have the question_id from prior POST request). But it costs me another ajax request, which I rather not do.If I could complete things with 1 request, then I rather stick with it.

Comment: You can use pushPayload to sideload the data and then call find based on the id, store.pushPayload('question', qdata);

Comment: I made changes as you mentioned. But it still makes 2 requests. Please look at my updated question above. Thanks.

Comment: pushpayload is a little wonky last I looked, they all needed to be the pluralized keys, so questions instead of question, I'd just change it up in the done