# Ember.js: Observing array property using @each doesn't work

Tags: arrays, ember.js

My understanding is that observing for '@each' means that I'm observing any change to any property in an array, but it doesn't seem to work.  For example:

```
App.ArrayProxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({

  i: 0,

  foo: function(){

    console.log('foo called');

    return ++this.i;

  }.property('content.@each')

});
```

I've also tried .property('@each') instead of .property('content.@each') with equally disappointing results.

Here is a jsbin that demonstrates: http://jsbin.com/hagar/5/edit

In the demo, changing the array list itself (by clicking the 'Remove Last' button) triggers a refresh of the 'foo' computed property, but changing a property of an object in the array doesn't.

Any way around this problem?

Comment: The key is telling Ember what property to watch. If you want to watch the name, it would be `'content.@each.name'`. http://jsbin.com/lehajeta/1/edit Just adding this on here in case it helps. Not trying to steal kingpin2k's thunder. :)

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte, what if I want to watch for any property change and not just 'name'?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you would do that? I am having trouble imagining a reason, even in the abstract. When you write a computed property callback, you are going to specify one or more properties to be used in the return value. Set those to be watched... If you end up with a list of five properties, you will at least be able to clearly see what is dynamically bound.

Comment: In terms of "why" it doesn't automatically watch for any and all property changes? I am guessing that it's for performance reasons. If you have a collection of 1000 models and you have a bunch of computed properties bound to every potential model property... CPU and memory wouldn't be happy.

Comment: My reason for this is I added a custom isDirty property on App.ArrayProxy.  In it, I do a deep comparison to check if the array is dirty.  I'm doing this to get around the fact that Ember Data doesn't support composite keys, so I've created a raw transform (similar to this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20645282/188740).  Because of this, I need to know when my array is dirty.

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense. Take a look at this: http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2014/03/11/cp-all-keys/ It looks a little clunky, but it may point you in the right direction. You seem to have a much more legitimate reason for doing this than the author did.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a setter (or the built in `incrementProperty`), I added name if you care when the name was changed.

```
  foo: function(){
    console.log('foo called');
    return this.incrementProperty('i');
  }.property('content.@each.name')
```

If you don't care about it incrementing when name changes you would use `foo.[]` which would only show when the array items are added/removed.

```
  foo: function(){
    console.log('foo called');
    return this.incrementProperty('i');
  }.property('content.[]')
```

http://jsbin.com/bakoqawi/1/edit

Comment: What if I want to watch for any property change, and not specify a particular property name?  My understanding was that .property('content.@each') should do that.

Comment: no, unfortunately there is no built in mechanism for watching if any property changes on an object.  You can dump them all into a single computed property and watch it if you needed that functionality.

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2K.  I was lead in the wrong direction when I saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22388402/188740.  The person asking that question somehow was able to observe any property of an array of objects, but it doesn't seems like it should have.

Comment: It looks like he converted his object into an array of property values (or key value pairs) and observed that.  That seems a little wonky to me, but it could be done.

Comment: Can it really be done? He's not observing a specific property, but rather the whole array itself --> observes("array.@each"). If that works for him, then shouldn't we be able to observe any property change as well?

Comment: He might have just been watching the fact that a new property was added.  I imagine his final solution didn't look like his question.

Comment: @Kingpin2k, can you please show us how to do what you commented? What I want to achieve is to observe the value inside the array...

Comment: @Melvin, are you looking to observe a specific known property, or all properties (known and unknown)?