# Differences on someArray.[] and someArray.@each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ember.js, ember-data

So I understand that Ember can compute on an array and elements within it. There are two options here.

**someArray.[]** and **someArray.@each**

If say I changed one of the element in array and there is a computed property that depends on it. Which one should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

someArray.[] will only be used when the array items are added/removed.

When the particular property in the array object is changed then someArray.@each will be called.

```
 isNameChanged: function() {
    console.log('is Name Changed')
 }.property('someArray.@each.name')
```

Can check this [Ember.js: Observing array property using @each doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892950/ember-js-observing-array-property-using-each-doesnt-work)

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you!